# Javascript: Sort array of arrays by second element in each inner array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

I have an array that looks like this:

```
const arr = [
  [500, 'Foo'],
  [600, 'bar'],
  [700, 'Baz'],
];
```

I would like to sort this `arr` alphabetically by the second element in each inner array, ie:

```
[
  [600, 'bar'],
  [700, 'Baz'],
  [500, 'Foo'],
]
```

Note the case insensitivity. Also, I would love to use lodash helpers if they come in handy here!

Comment: `Array.prototype.sort`, no lodash or anything else is required.

Comment: `_.orderBy(arr, x => x[1].toUpperCase())`

Comment: Read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), specifically the stuff about a custom compare function.

Comment: Well that was a fun discussion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a concrete, working example, using [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
const arr = [
  [500, 'Foo'],
  [600, 'bar'],
  [700, 'Baz']
];

arr.sort((a,b) => a[1].toUpperCase().localeCompare(b[1].toUpperCase()));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) takes a function which will be applied to each pair of items in the array. The return of that function determines how the items are sorted (it needs to return a positive number, 0, or a negative number).